# Algorithm for detecting recursion

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, recursion, integer

I am trying to implement a method that would be given an array of the first `k` integer values of a sequence. Based on the given values, the method would detect if it is possible to generate the values of the sequence using linear recurrence with integer coefficients.

1. If it's not possible, an error would be given.
2. If it is possible, the method would return an array `C` of the integer coefficients required to generate the sequence, of size `s <= k`, with `s` smallest as possible.

For the Fibonacci sequence, given the input `{0,1,1,2,3,5,13}`, the method would return `{1,1}`.

For the Tribonacci sequence, given the input sequence of at least 3 values, the method would return `{1,1,1}`

For a known recurrence relation `f(n) = f(n - 1) + f(n - 2) - 3 * f(n - 5) + 4 * f(n - 10)`, any input sequence of less than `10` values would return an error, but given a sequence of at least `10` consecutive values, the method would return `{1,1,0,0,-3,0,0,0,0,4}`, corresponding to the coefficients of the recurrence (zeroes in the `i`'th position of the array indicate that the `f(n - i)` value is not required).

Obviously the recurrence is not known in advance, it's just for simplicity I am giving examples with known recurrences. But the method would need to detect it by itself.

Can it even be done? Is there any known algorithm for this? I tried programming something in Java but really it's nothing more than a brute force, detecting **ALL** possible recurrences which isn't very helpful... I would love to see code samples of efficient attempts at this if it is possible or any points in the right direction.

**EDIT**

After some searching, I stumbled accros the **"Berlekamp–Massey algorithm"**, which seems related to this topic.

Comment: An exact algorithm for detecting a formula is impossible (in my view). Just imagine  something simple `f(n)=af(n-1)+bf(n-2), a,b integer`. How the variation will be done in this case for `a,b`? Next when abandon this try and add one more part to initial function `cf(n-3)`. Number of inputs params it's very important and if no limitation maybe the algorithm will be very inefficient. My point of view is that your problem is good for math theory but is less practical as topic here.(`key is algorithm, math related` and not any implementation in any language)

Comment: Looking further at given answer, seem you could detect linear-recursion.  So `a`,`b`,`etc` should be calculated after generating the equation system.

Answer (score 5):

Given a particular s, you get a linear equation (with s unknowns) for each element of the sequence after the first s.

For example, if s=2 and the sequence is 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8 then have unknowns a, b, and equations `1a + 1b = 2`, `1a + 2b = 3`, `2a + 3b = 5` and so on. You can try to solve these using any method for solving linear equations -- for example gaussian elimination. If s is small, then some of your equations need to be linear combinations of earlier ones, but gaussian elimination will find those for you. In this example, `2a+3b=5` is a linear combination of `1a+1b=2` and `1a+2b=3` (just add them up).

So you can try s=1, s=2, s=3 and so on, until you find a solution.